# Mudar ConnectionString para AppData/Roaming

Tags: c#

Minha aplicação instalou o banco de dados .mdf em AppData/Roaming. Agora preciso provavelmente mudar meu path da `ConnectionString` para este lugar. Como faço isso?

Li na internet sobre usar `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Mas aonde digito isso? No próprio `Form1.cs` onde fica o codigo todo?

No arquivo `app.config` tem essa liha de código:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseIris.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alterar com caminho relativo (recomendado):

```
    ConnectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf";
```

Alterar em tempo de execução de acordo com o executável:

```
    var executavelAtual = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    var diretorioAtual = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", diretorioAtual);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833640/connection-string-with-relative-path-to-the-database-file